# Handle iframe security issues (ex: 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN')

Tags: iframe, same-origin-policy, x-frame-options

Inside my application, I have an iframe that can open any webpages (99% of the time of the same origin). But the user can click in a link inside the iframe and go on an external website. I managed to detect if the website is of the same origin or not, but a request to a website such as "https://www.google.ca/" throw the following error:

**Refused to display 'https://www.google.ca/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.**

I have a beforeunload, onerror and onload event binded to my iframe, but I can't manage to handle this security issue with the event object.

Answer (score 0):

Have had same problem, loading 3rd party pages into my iframe some of them were blocked by X-Frame-Options that is not included into HTML.

NOTICE: working in CHROME,iPhone,Mozilla Android 4.4.2 BUT not working on FireFox.

If you want those pages to be opened in new window this is how i manage it.
Maybe usefull stuff for someone else searching solution for this particular scenario.

PHP (get_headers) works fine for most of them but i came accross few that did not give X-Frame-Options directly into HTML header (auto include), so get_headers failed and browser receive this [Load denied by X-Frame-Options: your_guest_url does not permit cross-origin framing.]

i had to add link on my first page to let users open problematic page in new window by clicking on it and create inbetween page with javascript,loading icon and setTimeout().

firstpage.php [with 'iframe' and 'a' below 'iframe']

```
<?php
foreach(get_headers("http://".$_REQUEST["address"]) as $v) {
    if($v == "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" || $v == "X-Frame-Options: DENY") {
    header("location: http://".$_REQUEST["address"]);
    die();
    }
}
?>

<iframe id="iframe-id" src="secondpage.php"></iframe>
<a href=your_guest_url>go to your_guest_url</a>

<script language='javascript'>
setTimeout(function() {
document.getElementById('iframe-id').src = 'your_guest_url';
},500);
</script>
```

secondpage.php [loaded into iframe]

```
<div class="loading-info">
    <div id="loading-info" class="loading-info-content">
            <i class="fa fa-3x fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
setTimeout(function() {
document.getElementById("loading-info").innerHTML = "<p'>USE LINK BELOW IFRAME</p>";
},5000);
</script>
```

page without 'hidden' X-Frame-Options loads via javascript into iframe after 500ms, problematic page won't load so secondpage stays in iframe and executes javascript setTimeout();.